# Toolbar overlaps activity under coordinate layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In an activity with a `ViewPager` and three fragments, I want to auto hide the `ToolBar`. For this, I am using `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`.

But the `ViewPager` is giving me some problem. If it is in `CoordinateLayout`, the `ToolBar` overlaps the activity. If it is outside `CoordinatorLayout` the `ToolBar` activity does not overlap the `WebView` activity. If the `ViewPager` is outside `CoordinatorLayout`, auto-hide does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

            <com.taadu.slidechat.adaptor.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have been experimenting with Linear layout, if `ViewPager` is in `LinearLayout` activity does not overlap, but this removes the function for Auto-hide.

I have added `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` in only one fragment to test Auto-hide. Please have a look.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dip"
            android:max="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/greenprogress" />

        <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/webViewTop"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/progressBar3"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is because you are giving `layout_behavior` to your `NestedScrollView` but not to your `ViewPager`

Add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your `ViewPage`

**i.e** your `ViewPager` should be like

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```